# Floating point addition, without floats!

Tags: code-golf, math, number, binary

Your task is to write a program, in any language, that adds two floating point numbers together WITHOUT using *any* fractional or floating point maths. Integer maths is allowed.

**Format**

The format for the numbers are strings containing 1's and 0's which represent the binary value of a [IEEE 754 32-bit float](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format). For example the number 2.54 would be represented by the string "01000000001000101000111101011100".

**Goal**

You program should input two numbers in the above mentioned format, add them together, and output the result in the same format. The shortest answer in any language wins!

**Rules**

Absolutly no floating point, decimal, or any kind of non-integer maths functions are allowed.

You can assume that the input is clean (i.e. contains only 1's and 0's).

You can assume that the inputs are numbers, and not Inf, -Inf, or NaN or subnormal. However, if the result is greater than the max value or smaller than the min value, you should return Inf and -Inf respectively. A subnormal (denormal) result may be flushed to 0.

You do not have to handle rounding properly. Don't worry if your results are a few bits out.

**Tests**

To test your programs, you can convert between decimal and floating point binary numbers using [this tool](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html).

1000 + 0.5 = 1000.5

```
01000100011110100000000000000000 + 00111111000000000000000000000000 = 01000100011110100010000000000000
```

float.MaxValue + float.MaxValue = Infinity

```
01111111011111111111111111111111 + 01111111011111111111111111111111 = 01111111100000000000000000000000
```

321.123 + -123.321 = 197.802

```
01000011101000001000111110111110 + 11000010111101101010010001011010= 01000011010001011100110101010000
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Python, 224 chars

This code converts a floating point input `f` to the integer `f*2^150`, does the addition using python native big integers, then converts back.

```
V=lambda x:((-1)**int(x[0])<<int(x[1:9],2))*int('1'+x[9:],2)
B=lambda x,n:B(x/2,n-1)+'01'[x&1]if n else''
def A(x,y):
 v=V(x)+V(y)
 s=e=0
 if v<0:s=1;v=-v
 while v>=1<<24:v/=2;e+=1
 if e>254:v=0
 return'%d'%s+B(e,8)+B(v,23)
```

Answer (score 3):

## J (172 characters)

Since IEEE 754 allows five rounding rules, I chose the "toward 0" rule. Here is my code:

```
b=:(_1&^)@".@{.*[:#.1x,("."0)@(9&}.),#.@:("."0)@}.@(9&{.)$0:
a=:b@[([:,(<&0)":"0@:,,@((8$2)&#:)@(-&24)@$@#:,}.@(24&{.)@#:@|)@(]`(**2x^278"_)@.((>&((2x^278)-2x^254))@|))@+b@]
```

The very same examples you give (but not exactly the same results because of the different rounding rule):

```
   '01000100011110100000000000000000' a '00111111000000000000000000000000'
01000100011110100010000000000000
   '01111111011111111111111111111111' a '01111111011111111111111111111111'
01111111100000000000000000000000
   '01000011101000001000111110111110' a '11000010111101101010010001011010'
01000011010001011100110101001111
```